# is this derailleur short cage or long cage?

Tags: derailleur

I'm selling the rear derailleur off this bike, and someone asked whether it's short or long cage. I assume it's long. Is this correct?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the pictures shown at [Jenson USA](http://www.jensonusa.com/Search?q=rear%20derailleur&qSrc=def), it appears to be a short cage, or perhaps a medium.  Although the picture you posted doesn't give a very good view of the derailleur. Take a look at the pictures in that link to judge for yourself.  Based on the information behind that link, it says that short cages are usually used for road bikes with a double crankset, while larger cages are used for triple cranksets or mountain bikes with a larger range of gears.  Since the pictures shows a road bike with a double crank set, I would again think that it is a short cage.

Comment: The real distinction, of course, is the number of teeth that the derailer can "absorb".  Suntour, eg, used to make a triple pulley derailer that could accommodate as many teeth as a standard long cage, even though the cage was no longer than the one pictured.

Comment: It's pretty obvious it's strictly short cage.

Answer (score 7):

Campagnolo derailleurs come in three lengths, short, medium and large.

To determine the size measure it. The centre to centre distance between the sprockets is 55, 72.5 and 89 mm and my guess is that you have a medium flavour rear derailleur...

How much are you selling it for, b.t.w.?

Comment: thanks it's 55mm, which would make it short. I sold it and the record shifters for $300.

Comment: Oops! I mean't short!